# How delete video from playList (dailyMotion API)?

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

> How i can delete video from playlist uses `dailyMotion API
>   (PHP)`?
>
> I was reading support but not found answer on my question. Offical
>   documentation:

```
[https://developer.dailymotion.com/use-cases#playlist-creation][1]
```

---

> I am found solution.

1. Login in DailyMotion
2. Go to https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools#/playlist and find
   "DELETE"

> Example PHP:

```
$api->delete("/playlist/".$playListId."/videos/".$videoId."");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph you should read for deleting videos from a playlist is the following: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#playlist-videos-connection-delete

Basically, a playlist's video is a video connection on the playlist object. To delete a video from a playlist, you have to delete this connection:

- you can issue a DELETE request to `/playlist/<PLAYLIST_ID>/videos/<VIDEO_ID>`
- also, if you want to delete the whole videos from the playlist, you can issue a POST request to `/playlist/<PLAYLIST_ID>/videos` with an empty *ids* query-string parameter

Indeed you can do it using the PHP SDK (see https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-php) :

```
$api->delete("/playlist/".$playListId."/videos/".$videoId."");
```

Or you can make a test call using the API Explorer https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools#/playlist/videos/delete

Comment: Thanks you !!!!! 
 - "also, if you want to delete the whole videos from the playlist, you can issue a POST request to /playlist/<PLAYLIST_ID>/videos with an empty ids query-string parameter" - really confortably)